# How to export text correctly to Word using DocX library

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I am trying simple to output some text from c# program to a new Word document but I have a weird problem: a lot of my output is coming upside down. Any word that doesn't end up with a letter is jumping to the end of the sentence. For example:

```
DocX doc= DocX.Create(filePath);
Paragraph p1 = template.InsertParagraph();
p1.AppendLine("This line contains a ").Append("bold").Bold().Append(" word.");
p1.AppendLine("Here is example with question mark?");
p1.AppendLine();
p1.AppendLine("Can you help me figure it out?");
p1.AppendLine();
```

[Output of the code](http://s18.postimg.org/wflcdtemh/example.jpg):

[image: Output of the code]

As you can see the sentences that end up with non letter are getting mixed up. I am using 2010 Office Word

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here, your code worked fine for me

Comment: Are you using 2010 OFFICE as well ?

Comment: What version of the library are you using?  .NET version ?

Comment: @MarkKGreenway I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.0.40219.1 SP1Rel , Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.5.50938 and the library version is 1.0.0.13

Answer (score 1):

Try instead

```
Paragraph p1 = template.InsertParagraph();
```

use this

```
Paragraph p1 = doc.InsertParagraph();
```